# Is there a term for words that are stronger than a similar counterpart? (e.g. Dislike vs. Hate)

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, terminology

Title says it all, but some more examples could be:

- *like* vs *love*
- *pleasure* vs *euphoria*
- *carelessness* vs *apathy*

etc.

...essentially words that carry more weight than their counterpart despite having similar definitions. I hesitate to call them *synonyms*- though that may not be incorrect to say, it isn't the term I'm looking for here.

Comment: I think this has something to do with Latinate register being more "genteel" than the register of words of Anglo-Saxon origin in the case of **dislike** vs **hate** where the **dis** prefix is Latinate. That the word comes from another language has something to do with how it comes to enter colloquial speech and develops connotations. If it's scientific lingo, or ruling class lingo, or street-business lingo, you end up with different results.

Comment: 'Careless vs apathetic' or 'carelessness vs apathy'! I don't think these are really counterparts; _carelessness_ is doing something without taking care, not 'not caring' about something.

Comment: They don't offer a term for this, but [this](https://www.google.com/books/edition/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B9%D1%81/fz3zCQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA188&printsec=frontcover) is somewhat relevant.

Comment: With adjectives, some are classed as **extreme**: _astounding_ > surprising; _furious_ > angry; _ancient_ > old; _gigantic_ > big .... See, for instance, [Vocabulary Home](https://vocabularyhome.com/category/adjectives-adverbs/).

Comment: What would be wrong with simple 'stronger'?

Comment: carelessness and apathy do not collocate like  your two other terms....I think you might mean: lack of caring because carelessness means not paying attention to something.

Comment: @Heartspring I realize I missed the train here, but "relative synonyms" sounds like it fits just fine. Why undersell? That should have been the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the three types of adjectives--positive, comparative, and superlative--are somewhat analogous to the three dyads or counterparts you provided in your question.

If you were to take the word *pleasure*, for example, and then rank it adjectivally, you would have:

- pleasurable
- more pleasurable
- most pleasurable

The dyads you have provided could be expanded into triads, as follows:

- fondness, like, and love (or, I'm fond of, I like, and I love)
- stimulation, pleasure, and euphoria (or, I'm stimulated, I'm pleasured, I'm euphoric
- detachment, complacence, and apathy (or, I'm detached, I'm complacent, and I'm apathetic, with my word *detached* as perhaps a better substitute for your word *carelessness*)

As for a way to name synonyms of varying strengths, I am at a loss to suggest a single word that fits the bill. I do, however, have some multiple-word suggestions:

- gradations of synonyms
- positive, comparative, and superlative synonyms
- rank order of synonyms, from less, to more, to most
- affective ranking of the intensity of synonyms
- varying valences of synonyms